# Two Image paths returned in onActivityResult are getting merged into one resulting in java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, arraylist, imageview, uri, filenotfoundexception

I'm using [android-image-picker](https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker) library for picking photos from Gallery.

Here's the code:

```
tapToUploadLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImagePicker.create(MainActivity.this)
                    .returnAfterFirst(false) // set whether pick or camera action should return immediate result or not. For pick image only work on single mode
                    .imageTitle("Tap to select") // image selection title
                    .single() // single mode
                    .multi() // multi mode (default mode)
                    .limit(3) // max images can be selected (99 by default)
                    .showCamera(true) // show camera or not (true by default)
                    .imageDirectory("Camera") // directory name for captured image  ("Camera" folder by default)
                    .enableLog(false) // disabling log
                    .start(REQUEST_CODE_PICKER); // start image picker activity with request code
        }
    });
```

Here's `onActivtyResult()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            ArrayList<Image> images = (ArrayList<Image>) ImagePicker.getImages(data);
            printImages(images);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Here's `printImages()`:

```
private void printImages(List<Image> images) {
        if (images == null) return;

        if (imageArray.size() >= 1) {
            imageArray.clear();
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).getPath()).append("\n");
            imageArray.add(Uri.parse(stringBuffer.toString().trim()));
        }
}
```

Now, I'm using this `imageArray` to set Image in `ImageView` like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Log.d("imageArrayContains", imageArray.get(position).toString());
imageView.setImageURI(imageArray.get(position));
```

The problem is that when I'm choosing just 1 image, it is getting set in the ImageView without any error but when I'm choosing 2 or more images, I'm getting this error:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Kwote/1506843168441.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Camera/IMG_20171001_035028145702152.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

because 2 filepaths are getting merged into one like this here: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Kwote/1506843168441.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Camera/IMG_20171001_035028145702152.jpg`

I'm unable to figure out how can I stop this from getting merged so that I can get all the chosen images loaded in my ImageView.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending both paths in a same StringBuilder.

Place it inside the for loop.

I believe you will not need a StringBuilder at all. Just use `imageArray.add(Uri.parse
(images.get(i).getPath().trim()));`